# Error with decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

My webservice code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=NOVA-PC;database=totev006;User ID=***;Password =***;");

    public Service () { }

    [WebMethod(Description = "Update return in Bet")]
    public string setReturn(int EventID)
    {
        string sql = "";
        decimal dcm = (decimal)100.5 + (decimal)45.055;
        int BetTypeWinID = 1;
        int BettorID = 1;
        int ins = 0;

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        sql = "update bet";
        sql += " set [return] = " + dcm;
        sql += " where event_id = " + EventID;
        sql += " and bet_type_id = " + BetTypeWinID;
        sql += " and bettor_id = " + BettorID;

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        ins += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (ins > 0)
            return "Ok";
        else
            return "not Ok";
    }
}
```

I get exception and this is the callstack:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near &#39;555&#39;.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Service.setReturn(Int32 EventID) in e:\Learning\Webservice\demo\webservice\App_Code\Service.cs:line 49
```

How to fix this?

Comment: it smells a decimal separator error. Try using a SqlParameter with your SqlCommand.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(sql)` please.

Comment: @user [return] type in database is decimal ?

Comment: Nobody should be creating queries like this : appending text and values! what happens if acutal values contains SQL instead of authorized values! Yes, use parameterized queries as RobIII said! Furthermore appending text should be done with StringBuilder, not string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is probably using a locale that formats 123.45 as 123,45.

Use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx) (see [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)) or [be specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx) in the formatting.

Whatever you do, [**DO NOT** "just" change the locale setting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx) to "fix" this problem.